# Using non-consecutive sequences to select indices from numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have a 2d numpy array, *matrix_a*, shaped 2x20. How do I select columns 5:8 and columns 15:18.

```
matrix_a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5...,19,20],
                     [1,2,3,4,5...,19,20]])
```

I want to select:

```
    [[5,6,7,15,16,17],
     [5,6,7,15,16,17]]
```

I can select the columns separately using `matrix_a[0,5:8]`, is there a way to select it all at once?

Barring 0-index vs 1-index, in MATLAB, all I would have to do is:

```
matrix_a(:,[5:8, 15:18])
```

Is there an analogous, simple command in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to combine the two slices, which is a convenient way to *Translate slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.* And it can accept mixed lists, arrays, scalars and slice notation, e.g. `np.r_[5, np.array([1,2]), [3]*2, 15:18]` is a validation construction as well, which gives `array([ 5,  1,  2,  3,  3, 15, 16, 17])`:

```
matrix_a = np.tile(np.arange(1, 21), 2).reshape(2, 20)

matrix_a[:, np.r_[5:8, 15:18]]
#array([[ 6,  7,  8, 16, 17, 18],
#       [ 6,  7,  8, 16, 17, 18]])
```