# Select non-consecutive row and column indices from 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have an array `a`

```
a = np.arange(5*5).reshape(5,5)

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

and want to select the last two columns from row *one* and *two*, and the first two columns of row *three* and *four*.

The result should look like this

```
array([[3,  4, 10, 11],
       [8,  9, 15, 16]])
```

How to do that in one go without indexing twice and concatenation?

I tried using [take](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821425/how-to-filter-numpy-array-by-list-of-indices)

```
a.take([[0,1,2,3], [3,4,0,1]])
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 0, 1]])
```

[ix_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62505046/what-does-numpy-ix-function-do-and-what-is-the-output-used-for)

```
a[np.ix_([0,1,2,3], [3,4,0,1])]
array([[ 3,  4,  0,  1],
       [ 8,  9,  5,  6],
       [13, 14, 10, 11],
       [18, 19, 15, 16]])
```

and [r_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47986668/using-non-consecutive-sequences-to-select-indices-from-numpy-array)

```
a[np.r_[0:2, 2:4], np.r_[3:5, 0:2]]
array([ 3,  9, 10, 16])
```

and a combination of ix_ and r_

```
a[np.ix_([0,1,2,3], np.r_[3:4, 0:1])]
array([[ 3,  0],
       [ 8,  5],
       [13, 10],
       [18, 15]])
```

Comment: Why you want to avoid indexing? Is there a specific reason behind?

Comment: That last combination of `ix_` and `r_` looks good.  You could use `np.array([0,1,2,3])[:,None]` directly for the first dimension index.  In short, you need to use `advanced indexing`, with 2 arrays that `broadcast` against each other.

Comment: @lemon I wanted to avoid indexing **twice** in combination with concatenation, because I consider one indexing step as more elegant and performant.

Comment: More elegant most likely, more performant I don't know...

Comment: @hpaulj Can you turn it into a working solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [integer advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), you can do something like this

```py
index_rows = np.array([
    [0, 0, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 3, 3],
])

index_cols = np.array([
    [-2, -1, 0, 1],
    [-2, -1, 0, 1],
])

a[index_rows, index_cols]
```

where you just select directly what elements you want.